# Bada linker does not complain on missing symbols, runtime crashes possible

Tags: linker, runtime-error, bada, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Take a sample bada app, any one. For example, "BasicApp". Into MainForm.cpp, insert the following:

```
extern void Hello();
```

Do not define the function anywhere. Then under `MainForm::OnInitializing`, place a call to it:

```
MainForm::OnInitializing(void)
{
    Hello();
    //...
```

The app compiles and links just fine, and runs up to that line. Then crashes. The crash does not come up as a breakpoint in debugger.

SDK 2.0.5, targeting bada 2.0 HVGA. All settings are defaults.

What's up with that linker behavior? How can I make it, well, check for unresolved symbols, like every other linker in existence does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT courtesy of tech support:

Add the option `-Wl,--no-undefined` by right clicking on your project in the project Explorer->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->bada C++ Linker->Miscellaneous->Linker flags.